# How to receive global link using Firebase Dynamic Links for Android

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Let's assume First user send invitation to second user.
User send some global link and second user receive it.
In my case user received `dynamic link` instead of `global link` in Android device.

I would like to share current uri `https://aewp.com/share`

```
private void shareVocabulary() {
    Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Text")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setDeepLink(createDynamicLink().getUri())
            .setCustomImage(Uri.parse("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/info.jpg"))
            .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.install))
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, SHARE_RESULT_CODE);
}

public DynamicLink createDynamicLink(){

        String domain = getString(R.string.domain) + ".app.goo.gl";

        return FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink().
                setLink(Uri.parse("https://aewp.com/share")).
                setDynamicLinkDomain(domain).
                setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder(getPackageName()).
                        setFallbackUrl(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())).
                        build()
                ).
                buildDynamicLink();
    }
```

**DeepLinkActivity.class**

In following code each time returned dynamic link, instead of global link

```
 FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().getDynamicLink(getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
                        if (data == null) {
                            Logger.logInfo(getClass(), "getInvitation: no data");
                            return;
                        }

                        // Get the deep link
                        Uri link = data.getLink();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Logger.logError(getClass(), "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                    }
                });
```

As far as I undersand I should recive this link **"https://aewp.com/share"** instead of short or large dynamic link

How can I fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a little bit difference between Intent types
To `Firebase AppInviteInvitation` we does not use deep link, instead of it we should pass dynamic link.

```
    Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Send")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setDeepLink(R.string.global_link).build())
            .setCustomImage(Uri.parse("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9.jpg"))
            .setCallToActionText("Install"))
            .build();
    startActivityForResult(intent, SHARE_RESULT_CODE);
```

While send data using `Intent.ACTION_SEND`,  We need to use a dynamic link for different platforms

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Text here " + createDynamicLink().getUri().toString());
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose one"));
```